# How to use Linear.V to write static type checked matrix operations (Haskell)?

Tags: haskell, types, existential-type

I'm interested in using `Linear.V` from the [`Linear` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.15.5/docs/Linear-V.html) to write matrix operations on sizes that are known at compile time. However, I'm not sure how to use this library. Where can I find more references on how to use it?

Comment: You know you can already do this using hmatrix? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.16.1.3/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Static.html. And you get the full power of LAPACK behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little tricky to ask without a bit more knowledge of what exactly you want to do, but I'll take a stab. `Linear.V` gives you *n*-dimensional vectors for any *n*. In `linear`, matrices are defined as vectors-of-vectors - `Linear.Matrix` defines the operations on such values. `Linear.Matrix` works over various sizes of matrix by being parameterized over two functors, and `Linear.V` is indeed a `Functor` so we're good to use those operations.

The following boring example shows how you could work with `Linear.V`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
import Linear
import Linear.V
import Data.Vector

identity :: V 2 (V 2 Float)
identity = V (fromList [ V (fromList [1, 0]), V (fromList [0, 1]) ])

calculation :: V 2 (V 2 Float)
calculation = identity !*! identity
```

It's boring in that it just calculates the product of two identity matrices, but it should give you an idea how to put these pieces together. I'm using GHC 7.6+ type literals to specify that `identity` is a *2x2* matrix.

Note that using the `V` constructor is somewhat dangerous - it allows you to "lie" about the size of the vector. For example, if you do the following:

```
identity :: V 2 (V 2 Float)
identity = V (fromList [ V (fromList [1, 0]) ])
```

things are likely to go *very* wrong. It's safer to use `fromVector`, or perhaps `tabulate` (`tabulate` uses the representation of `V` - which is basically a function from element index to its value).